# unable to modify data in a masked array. arr[i] vs arr.data[i]

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wasn't expecting the following behaviour when modifying data in a masked array. It seems that some values can be modified using the [] operand but not all of them. However if you do it accessing its data attribute then you can modify all.  This only happens if there is True value in mask for a cell in the tuple (all operations related to the masked array seem to be working properly).

can anybody explain why?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import numpy.ma as ma
>>> arr = ma.ones(nrows, dtype=[('c1', np.int),('c2', np.int)])
>>> arr.mask[1][0] = True
>>> arr[1][1] = 3
>>> arr[0][0] = 4
>>> arr
masked_array(data = [(4, 1) (--, 1) (1, 1)],
         mask = [(False, False) (True, False) (False, False)],
   fill_value = (999999, 999999),
        dtype = [('c1', '<i8'), ('c2', '<i8')])

>>> arr.data[1][1]=5
>>> arr
masked_array(data = [(4, 1) (--, 5) (1, 1)],
         mask = [(False, False) (True, False) (False, False)],
   fill_value = (999999, 999999),
        dtype = [('c1', '<i8'), ('c2', '<i8')])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a bug.  Here is what is happening.

When you use (which works as desired)

```
arr.data[1][1]=5
```

the function `_get_data()` is used and a simple view of the underlying nparray is returned.

When you use (which works incorrectly)

```
arr[1][1]=5
```

the function `__getitme__()` is used.  First, it goes in and tries to grab row 1.  It detects that one of the items on this row is masked and returns a masked copy of the row (instead of a view onto the array).  The underlying problem is with this line of ma\core.py (line 2996 of the version currently on [github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/ma/core.py)):

```
dout = mvoid(dout, mask=mask, hardmask=self._hardmask)
```

The mvoid function is returning a copy of row 1 (which includes a mask of value `[1][0]`) instead of a view onto row 1.  When the column index is then processed, it is making a change onto the copy instead of a view.

Why this works on rows which do not contain a mask is that the view is returned instead of the `movid()` copy.

This whole copy vs view thing is a pretty classic gotcha with numpy.  To be fair to the developers, given how `__getitem__()` must function for masked arrays (ie, it must return a masked copy when reading values) I'm not sure how they can work around it.  But it might be worth a bug ticket to see if anyone more cleaver than I has an idea.

Answer (score 2):

The getter `arr[i][j]` is not listed in the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#accessing-the-data) as a proper way to access data. It gives 4 others ways instead, and I tried 3 of them:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.ma.ones(3, dtype=[('c1', np.int),('c2', np.int)])
>>> arr.mask[0][1] = arr.mask[1][1] = arr.mask[2][1]= True
>>> arr.data[0][0] = 2              # data attribute
>>> np.ma.getdata(arr)[1][0] = 3    # ma.getdata function
>>> arr.__array__()[2][0] = 4       # __array__() method
>>> print(arr)
[(2, --) (3, --) (4, --)]
```